# Python MultiProcessing : Kill child process based on event in parent process

Tags: python, while-loop, multiprocessing

Let's say I have the below code:

```
quit = Event()
while True:
    if something > max_size:
        quit.set()
        break 
    else:
        p1 = Process(target=B(argv).calc(value, quit), name="d")
```

where B looks like the below:

```
class B:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.argv = argv
    def calc(self, value, quit):
        while not quit.is_set():
             while True:
                 for c in value:
                      ##Do some logic....
```

What I'm trying do to in the worker task of B.calc is that as long as the quit event is not set by the main process, then the B().calc() function should keep running. The while loop in B().calc() is required as I'm trying to implement rolling over of files based on some logic. So, the moment quit event is set by the main process, I would like to kill the child process.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: You can’t have B.calc() quit “as soon as” the event is set. You can have it quit shortly after. You could have ‘if quit.is_set(): return’ inside the for loop.

Comment: @quamrana is right, once the event is set, you have to wait until the worker process will check if it's true on the next `while` loop iteration. There is another way to stop the worker, you can terminate it when needed. The drawback of this is that the worker will have no chance to finish gracefully and to clean up.

Comment: Using `Event` is already the best option you have.

Comment: Okay, I have tweaked my code for that and also removed the P1.join() which I had in my code. That solved my issue. 
@constt - I don't want the worker to gracefully finish and shut down. That was out of scope for my particular exercise, but I see what you mean.